# C error: request for member ___ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, list, compiler-errors, linked-list, hashtable

So the code is saying that List and size is not a structure?

```
typedef struct HashTable{
    int size;
    ListRef **List; 
} hash;

typedef struct hash *hash_ref;

hash_ref *newHash(int size){
    hash_ref *hashed= NULL;
    if(size<1){
        return NULL;
    }
    if( (hashed=malloc(sizeof(hash))) ==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    if( (hashed->List=malloc(sizeof(ListRef*)*size)) ==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        hashed->List[i]=NULL;
    }
    hashed->size=size;

    return hashed;
}
```

Here is my List function

```
typedef struct Node{
    long key;/*book id*/
    ListRef data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
}NodeType;

typedef NodeType* NodeRef;

typedef struct ListHdr{
    NodeRef first;
    NodeRef last;
    NodeRef current;
    long length;
}ListHdr;
```

I was wondering whats up with this error? I forgot to add that ListHdr is changed to ListRef in my List header file.. Which is included in my hashtable module.

I'm currently trying to create 2 hash tables. One has table stores 2 long integers. The other hashtable takes 1 long integer and a linked list(which has 2 long integers).

Comment: What line is getting this and where is hash_ref defined?

Comment: Please post more code, because it's not compilable here.

Comment: THe lines with hashed->List(both malloc and List[i]) and hashed->size

Comment: hash ref is defined in my header file as typedef struct hash *hash_ref;

Comment: Uhh, what is "struct hash"?  I don't think that exists.  Only struct HashTable -- see answer below

Answer (score 3):

`hash_ref` is typedefed to a *pointer* to `hash`, so you must declare `hashed` as `hash_ref hashed`, not `hash_ref *hashed`. (The latter would effectively create a pointer to pointer to `hash`.)

In addition to this, you should omit `struct` from the typedef that declares `hash_ref`. Currently `hash_ref` isn't declared to point `hash`, but to an as-yet-undeclared `struct hash`. That compiles only because the compiler interprets it as a forward declaration of a `struct hash`. This interpretation will cause any code that tries to dereference `hash_ref` to fail with errors such as "storage size of `struct hash` unknown".

Answer (score 1):

It means you're either calling `.` on something that isn't a struct or union OR `->` on a pointer that isn't a pointer directly to a struct or union.

hash_ref * hashed is a DOUBLE pointer to HashTable.  A single dereference still gives you a HashTable pointer, which isn't a union or struct.

Comment: I'm not seeing what I'm missing here. hashed is a struct with a size and a linked list. If I take the pointers off of newHash and hashed, I get a derefenciong pointer error.

Comment: Oh that fixed my problem. Thank you! What's the difference between HashTable and hash exactly? Is hash just a nickname for HashTable? Sorry for the noob questions, I ahven;t programmed in C in 3 years so I;m a little rusty!

Comment: actually I really don't remember.  the other answer actually got it first, so send him an upvote, too :)

Comment: @user2388648 `hash` is a typedef for `struct HashTable`. `hash_ref` is a typedef for `struct hash *` (which doesn't really make sense, since `hash` is not a struct). As its name implies, `hash_ref` is already a *reF*, so you don't need to declare a `hash_ref *hashed`. `hash_ref hashed` would be sufficient.

Comment: yeah my real question was really just if typedefing a typedef'd struct as a struct could work.  I can't try it right now.  But it seems like you're saying typedef struct struct HashMap foo

Comment: @xaxxon That's a good question. Such a `typedef` is legal C, but it's not immediately obvious why. Since structs and typedefs are in different namespaces, `typedef struct hash *hash_ref` actually constitutes a *forward declaration* of a `struct hash` and a declaration of a `hash_ref` typedef for `struct hash *`. This is unintended and will cause errors like "storage size of struct hash unknown" later down the line. I've now amended my answer to address this issue.

Comment: OK, so it's syntactically valid, but doesn't do what was intended which was to create a type which is * to HashMap.  Instead it created a forward declaration to a struct hash that doesn't exist- only the typedef hash, which isn't the same.